# PHP session_cache_limiter mixes up sessions when set

Tags: php, caching

I'm developing a website with my roommate. Right now the site has 1,000 members. Currently I need to put `session_cache_limiter('nocache');` at the top of all my pages. If I don't, when my roommate and I are the website at the same time, occasionally the sessions seem to get mixed up. Meaning he will see my username in his account, or vice-versa. I'm assuming this has something to do with both of us using the same IP, right? I don't know for sure what's causing it, so I'm afraid if I turn caching back on the users on my website will have the same problem. I've switched the website to 3 different servers since the website has been launched and they've all had the same issue when caching is turned on. Any ideas how to fix this issue so I can turn caching turned on?